'numpy.float64' object is not iterable error when using an array
I am trying to evaluate an ARIMA model.
To evaluate the model, I want to use 5 days into the future as test data.
forecast_data = model_fit.forecast(steps=5)

# Last 5 days of forecast data
pred_arima_y = forecast_data[0].tolist()

# 5 days of actual data
test_y = appl_test_df.price.values

# Minimum forecast data for the last 5 days
pred_y_lower = []
# Maximum forecast data for the last 5 days
pred_y_upper = []

for lower_upper in forecast_data[2]:
    lower = lower_upper[0]
    upper = lower_upper[1]
    pred_y_lower.append(lower)
    pred_y_upper.append(upper)

And I get the following error
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-309f07141e72> in <cell line: 16>()
     14 pred_y_upper = []
     15 
---> 16 for sub_array in forecast_data[2]:
     17     for lower_upper in sub_array:
     18         lower = lower_upper[0]

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable


To fix the code, I tried using a nested loop to iterate over the entire 2D array forecast_data[2], or tried other methods, but they all failed.
I added some more code to the previous one.
The preceding partial code looks like this.
ARIMA was not available, so we switched to SARIMAX halfway through.
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax import SARIMAX
import statsmodels.api as sm

# model = ARIMA(appl_train_df.price.values, order = (2,1,2))
# model_fit = model.fit(trend = 'c', full_output = True, disp = True)

model = SARIMAX(endog = appl_train_df.price.values, order = (2, 1, 2), seasonal_order = (1, 1, 1, 12))
model_fit = model.fit(trend = 'c', full_output = True, disp = True)
# model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)

print(model_fit.summary())

                                      SARIMAX Results                                       
============================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                                    y   No. Observations:                  515
Model:             SARIMAX(2, 1, 2)x(1, 1, [1], 12)   Log Likelihood               -3919.268
Date:                              Tue, 02 Apr 2024   AIC                           7852.536
Time:                                      01:36:55   BIC                           7882.066
Sample:                                           0   HQIC                          7864.122
                                              - 515                                         
Covariance Type:                                opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ar.L1          1.8483      0.012    154.720      0.000       1.825       1.872
ar.L2         -0.9506      0.011    -82.778      0.000      -0.973      -0.928
ma.L1         -1.8954      0.010   -187.159      0.000      -1.915      -1.876
ma.L2          0.9839      0.010     98.924      0.000       0.964       1.003
ar.S.L12       0.1830      0.018     10.002      0.000       0.147       0.219
ma.S.L12      -0.9623      0.032    -30.038      0.000      -1.025      -0.900
sigma2      2.977e+05   1.44e+04     20.616      0.000    2.69e+05    3.26e+05
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (L1) (Q):                   1.85   Jarque-Bera (JB):               665.47
Prob(Q):                              0.17   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.35   Skew:                             0.05
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.00   Kurtosis:                         8.64
===================================================================================

And I checked the value with

print(forecast_data[2].shape)

, but the result is

( )

, It is very strange.

Can you print out the value of forecast_data.shape, and add it to the question?

The error means that forecast_data[2] is ONE number, and thus forecast_data is a 1d array.  Did you examine forecast_data?  Its shape, dtype etc.  Review the docs for model_fit.forecast to make sure you understand what it's supposed to produce?

yes, a numpy.float64 object will have () shape, like a 0d single item array.

If so, can you tell me how to fix it?

Why are you trying to iterate on this thing?  You have not explained your intent.  Or if this isn't ypur code, you need to go back to the source.  This isn't a simple syntax error.  There's a mismatch between the data, whatever the source, and the code assumptions.
